# How to make validation for request body that field of the it is digit?

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot, spring-validator

I try to implement simple controller in Spring Boot. And I want to validate that companyId field from incoming input is digit?

MyEntity:

```
 @Data
 public class BoardRequestDTO {

    private Integer companyId;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Can't be empty")
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Can't be empty")
    private String code;
 }
```

My Controller's route:

```
 @PostMapping
 public ResponseEntity<Board> createBoard(@Valid @RequestBody BoardRequestDTO boardRequestDTO) {}
```

I have the correctly implemented ExeptionHendler to MethodArgumentNotValidException that correctly handle not empty case for other fields. 
But for example when I send request with the following request body I get just 400 status without any messages and any exceptions in my console:

```
{
    "companyId": "ssdcdsdcds",
    "code": "",
    "name": null
}
```

How can I correctly handle case when somebody send string instead of digit?

Answer (score 0):

`@Min(0)` should fix it for you.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Comment: Unfortunatelly, It is doesn't work.  If I rigth understand @Min check a field of the  already created BoardRequestDTO instance and than validate. I guess In my case It happens before validation. It just can't to create BoardRequestDTO  instance and throw some parsing exception because can't put "ssad" to int. It doesn't  come to validation stage.

Comment: Do you have @Validated annotation in your controller ?

Comment: Validated isn't necessary when you work with @Valid and validate request body. All other validation annotations in class work without any problem.

Comment: Can you post your Controller class ?